# UWP System.AccessViolationException upon using LoadFromStream on RichEditBox document

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a RichEditBox with its content set as a file. Rarely, upon calling the method, it drops this exception:

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

This is the code:

```
var RAS = await TXTFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

RTB.Document.LoadFromStream(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, RAS);
```

This bug can be reproduced by calling the method very quickly in a row with DispatcherTimer, but the app must run for about 10 or 15 minutes for this to occur.

Edit: here is some additional code:

```
    private void REB_SelectionChanged(object Sender, RoutedEventArgs EvArgs)
    {
        //Autosave
        if (AutoSaveSwitch.IsOn == true)
        {
            TriggerAutosave();
        }
    }

    public void TriggerAutosave()
    {
        if (DTSave.IsEnabled != true) DTSave.Start();
    }
    private void DTSave_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (AutoSaveSwitch.IsOn == true && TXTFile != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (TXTFile != null)
                {
                    if (AutoSaveSwitch.IsOn == true)
                    {
                        AutosaveWritingToFile();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SaveIndicatorGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    SaveIndicatorGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception EX)
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {
            DTSave.Stop();
        }
    }

    readonly DispatcherTimer DTSave = new DispatcherTimer();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DTSave.Interval = new TimeSpan((int)1.5);
        DTSave.Tick += DTSave_Tick;
    }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior on myside with the code you posted. Can you try to add a `Task.wait()` to make the code wait for 1s to see if it helps?

Comment: I delayed the DispatcherTimer to 1.5 seconds and it still didn't help

Comment: Could you please tell me in which line of the code gives the error? `OpenAsync` or `LoadFromStream`?

Comment: LoadFromStream. I tried to take a screenshot of the error but it doesn't want to throw the exception again.

Comment: Could you please share more code about `calling the method very quickly in a row with DispatcherTimer`? I'm trying to reproduce this behavior on my side.